# How to access using NASM to bitmap screen data

Tags: screen, nasm, pixel

I would like to know if you can access the screen array. I would like to read and write in this part to change a pixel color, for example. I hope it could be understood. Thanks

Comment: please post what you have tried and what problems you ran into.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't have any code. I only would like to know how to access to the memory location where the pixels data are.

Comment: You will need to give more context. What operating system, for start?

Comment: I'm sorry! I'm using windows with a 64 bits processor. I know how to do it in DOS mode, but I would like to do this in Windows

Comment: https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/assembly/threads/229040/nasm-painting-pixels

Comment: There's no "screen array" that you write to in Windows. Create a fullscreen window and draw to it using the GDI bitmap functions (e.g. `SetDIBits` / `StretchDIBits`), or by displaying a quad that covers the entire window with Direct3D / OpenGL and doing your drawing in a pixel/fragment shader.

Comment: Ok... I liked to have a full control, but Windows security is...